# Send POST request to Jira using API token

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, jira-rest-api

I have working `curl` command for Jira ticket creation which I cannot reproduce in `python3`. `HTTPBasicAuth` and `HTTPDigestAuth` methods from [authentication with python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) doc are not working with an API key.

Please find mentioned `curl` and `python` code below.

Bash:

```
curl -vL -u "my@email:API_KEY" -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data "$DATA" https://jira-url/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Python:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'
}

url = https://jira-url

response = requests.post('{0}/rest/api/2/issue/'.format(url),
                         headers=headers,
                         data=data,
                         auth=requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(user_email, api_key),
                         verify=False,
                         allow_redirects=True)
```

I get an error `400 Bad Request for url: URL`

Comment: I converted comment with answer, are you sure `data` is an object and not a json string ?

Comment: @Blusky yes, `data` is specified the same as headers. `print(type(data))` returns `<class 'dict'>`

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
headers = {
    'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'
}

data = {"var1": "val1", "var2": "val2"}

url = https://jira-url

response = requests.post('{0}/rest/api/2/issue/'.format(url),
                         headers=headers,
                         json=data,
                         auth=requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(user_email, api_key),
                         verify=False,
                         allow_redirects=True)
```

(I replaced `data` argument with `json`, and I removed `Content-Type` from headers as `requests` will automaticaly detect it).

You want `data` to be a Python object and not a json string.

Comment: Changing `data` to `json` returns the same `400` HTTP error. Regarding `Content-Type` - I cannot remove that.